# Error with latex when using the package babel option with TexStudio

Tags: latex, texstudio

I am writing the following code in TeXstudio:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{report}

% Este pacote abaixo é relacionado à acentuação.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Isso é um capítulo}

    \section{Esta é a primeira seção}
    \section*{Esta é uma seção}
    Meu primeiro documento. É isso aí
    \subsection{Esta é uma subseção}
    Conteúdo subseção

    \subsubsection*{Esta é uma subsubseção}

\end{document}
```

And with option brazil at babel package I receive the error bellow:

| File | Type | Line | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| babel.sty | error | line 1042 | Package babel Error: Unknown option `brazil'. Either you misspelled it. \ProcessOptions* |

I am using:`Ubuntu 22.04`, `TeXstudio 4.2.1` and `babel 2020/09/01 3.48 The Babel package`

I have already try to remove and install:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install textlive-lang-all
```

and nothing works....

What is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel), from the list of available languages on page 47 you have: portuguese followed by brazilian. I think settings `babel` to `brazilian` should work but you can also add a modifier to the main language Portuguese, that is `portuguese.brazilian` (see p. 8). `brazil` is an old name used to be used when names had to be shortened to 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

There were two different packages locations in my machine.

```
~/.Tinytex
```

and

```
/usr/share/texlive
```

I have deleted the `.Tinytex` and everything works right now.